# what is best approach to query based on navigation property with EntityFramework

Tags: entity-framework, express, navigation-properties

Consider these two classes:

```
class Invoice {
    // some props ... 
    public virtual List<InvoiceStatusLog> StatusLogs { get; set; }
}

class StatusLogs {
    public InvoiceStatus Status { get; set; }
    public int InvoiceID { get; set; }
    public virtual Invoice Invoice { get; set; }
}
```

What I want is to get invoices by their last status witch is last `StatusLog` status.
I can do something like this:

```
var invoices = repository.SelectList(c => (c.Date >= _fromDate && c.Date <= _toDate)
             && (c.StatusLogs.OrderBy(l => l.CreateDate).Last().Status == InvoiceStatus.Paid || c.StatusLogs.OrderBy(l => l.CreateDate).Last().Status == InvoiceStatus.MinorPaid));
```

However, I really don't think this would be good idea as matter of performance and  coding (repeating some expression everywhere ).

I know I can write a function which generates an expression based on status and can use that expression in body of `selectList()`, but first we have various conditions based on status ( && ... || && && .. ) and cant be generalized, and second: again I don't believe something like:

```
c.StatusLogs.OrderBy(l => l.CreateDate).Last().Status == InvoiceStatus.MinorPaid
```

would have good performance.
I would appreciate any suggestion

Comment: Have you done any performance testing or are you guessing?

Comment: @ErikEJ no in fact Im guessing , but consider thousands of invoice and bunch of status per each invoice ...

Comment: I think not guessing would be a good approach

Comment: When facing issues like this where the most current status has a fairly significant purpose, I would argue that a bit of de-normalization is justified. For instance giving each invoice a CurrentStatusId field / CurrentStatus property which will be maintained as the most recent status from the history. A background SQL job can run against the DB to detect and report on any cases where a CurrentStatusId does *not* reflect the latest status reference, so that developers can investigate possible cases where status changes are not being tracked properly.

Comment: You can at least do a `new[] {InvoiceStatus.MinorPaid, InvoiceStatus.Paid}.Contains(c.StatusLogs.OrderBy(l => l.CreateDate).Last().Status)` to ensure there is only a single lookup.